# AJAX load more for different custom post type loops

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, ajax

I have 3 page templates. Each page template has a different custom post type: `cpt_music`, `cpt_tv` and `cpt_cine`. Each loop has a AJAX load more function.

The PHP code of the function:

```
function mysite_loadmore_ajax_handler_event(){

    if (is_page_template('page-template-1.php')) :
        $current_post_type = 'cpt_music';

    elseif (is_page_template('page-template-1.php')) :
        $current_post_type = 'cpt_tv';

    elseif (is_page_template('page-template-1.php')) :
        $current_post_type = 'cpt_cine';

    endif;

    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    $args['post_type'] = $current_post_type;
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 4;

    $query_ajax_event = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query_ajax_event->have_posts() ) : while ( $query_ajax_event->have_posts() ) : $query_ajax_event->the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'cpt-archive' );

    endwhile;

    endif;
    die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadcpt', 'mysite_loadmore_ajax_handler_event'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadcpt', 'mysite_loadmore_ajax_handler_event'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

The AJAX code:

```
$('#load-more').click(function(){
    var button = $(this),
        data = {
        'action': 'loadcpt',
        'query': posts_myajax,
        'page' : current_page_myajax
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : '.../admin-ajax.php',
        data : data,
        type : 'POST',
        beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
            button.hide();
        },
        success : function( data ){
            if( data ) {
                $('.wrapper').append(data); // Display result posts

                isInView();

                button.show(); // Insert new posts

                current_page_myajax++;

                if ( current_page_myajax == max_page_myajax )
                    button.remove(); // If last page, remove the button
            } else {
                //button.remove(); // If no data, remove the button as well
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I could write 3 different PHP functions to handle the AJAX of the 3 loops. But I would like to make things a bit more smooth and have a single function covering the 3 loops.

As you can see I'm trying to create 3 different variables related to the page templates. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I struggle to find a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You should [localize the current page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) and pass it to the ajax callback. If I remember correctly, admin-ajax is page agnostic.

Comment: Thank you @Howdy_McGee, unfortunately I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: `is_page_template` does not make sense in an AJAX context, there is no main loop, current post/page, or current template in an AJAX request. If you want `cpt_tv` but not `cpt_music` you have to pass that information along in your request. Remember, the request that served the page is different from the request that serves the AJAX, they're not the same, and the AJAX handler does not have the pages context, it only has what the javascript gave it